# Best way to echo variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, echo

From what I've read, it isn't possible to echo more PHP code within an echo so I'm after a solution to the following:

Basically, if the 'closed_state' column in my DB equals 'yes', display a link with a variable on the end else display a different link with a variable on the end.

Here's my code:

```
<?php 

$result1    = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT closed_state FROM tbl_company WHERE company_id='$company_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$result2    = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT company_id FROM tbl_company WHERE company_id='$company_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$result3    = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT company_id FROM tbl_company WHERE company_id='$company_id'") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    if ($row['closed_state'] == "yes")
    {
        echo "<a href="customers_open.php?company_id=<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) echo "{$row['company_id']}"; ?>">Reopen account</a>";
    } else {  
        echo "<a href="customers_close.php?company_id=<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) echo "{$row['company_id']}"; ?>">Close account</a>";
    }
}   

?>
```

Obviously it doesn't work so what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I just really want you to know you can do this... `SELECT company_id, closed_state FROM...` and then use `$row['company_id']` and `$row['closed_state']` without having to make multiple trips to the db.

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries. If you're selecting 3 columns, you should do it all in one query instead of 3 separate queries. Then when you're selecting a single row you would use `mysqli_fetch_row()` instead of using a while loop.

Comment: The problem I have with using one query is I can only seem to use `$row['company_id']` once. If there's a way around it I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need 3 queries. One should be fine selecting both values. Queries 2 & 3 are identical anyway.

```
$result1    = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT company_id, closed_state FROM tbl_company WHERE company_id='$company_id'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    if ($row['closed_state'] == "yes"){
        echo '<a href="customers_open.php?company_id='.$row['company_id'].'">Reopen account</a>';
    }else{  
        echo '<a href="customers_close.php?company_id='.$row['company_id'].'">Close account</a>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP isn't recursively embeddable, or executable. You cannot embed php code in a php string and have it executed automatically, e.g.

```
<?php

$foo = "This is a <?php echo 'string'; ?> in PHP";
echo $foo;
```

will give you the literal output:

```
This is a <?php echo 'string'; ?> in PHP
```

instead of the

```
This is a string in PHP
```

that you want it to.

If you want to "embed" php like that, just build a string:

```
 $foo = "This is a " . 'string' . " in PHP";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly quoting your strings. If you have the string `echo "foo"bar"` then then middle double-quote will cause PHP to end the string and try to parse `bar` as something else.

Likewise, you cannot nest PHP inside of PHP.

```
    echo '<a href=....<?php while($row...
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume that you're second and third queries are actually different, otherwise there is no point in having duplicates - but here is a working version.

```
<?php 

$result1    = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT closed_state FROM tbl_company WHERE company_id='$company_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$result2    = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT company_id FROM tbl_company WHERE company_id='$company_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$result3    = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT company_id FROM tbl_company WHERE company_id='$company_id'") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    if ($row['closed_state'] == "yes")
    {
        $company_id = null;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) $company_id = $row['company_id'];
        echo "<a href='customers_open.php?company_id={$company_id}'>Reopen account</a>";
    } else {
        $company_id = null;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) $company_id = $row['company_id'];
        echo "<a href='customers_close.php?company_id={$company_id}'>Close account</a>";
    }
}   

?>
```

Comment: Why would you assume that? It's selecting from the same table using the same ID. How could it possibly be different?

Comment: He may have used those queries as examples. Obviously if it were actually those queries then he could do it in one.

Comment: No, the second and third are actually the same. For some reason I couldn't use $company_id more than once in some previous code so I've had to make multiple calls to the DB for the same thing.